# Difference between StartActivity and FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, fragment

What is the difference between

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeworkPagerActivity.class);
i.putExtra(HomeworkFragment.EXTRA_HOMEWORK_ID, c.getId());
startActivity(i);
```

and:

```
HomeworkFragment newFragment = new HomeworkFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(HomeworkFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();
```

I'm using a Fragment to launch another Fragment.

However, which one should be used and why?

Additionally, I need to transmit data from the child Fragment (HomeworkFragment) back to the Fragment that launched it in the first place. Which setup allows data (like an id number) to be transmitted easily?

Comment: "which one should be used and why?" : IMHO you should use neither of them. The design philosophy for Fragments is that they should be self-contained and re-usable. If a `Fragment` "knows" about a particular `Activity` or another `Fragment` you've broken that model. As Little Child mentions, your Fragments can define interfaces and use those to communicate with the parent `Activity` and that should allow indirect control and communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, look.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeworkPagerActivity.class);
i.putExtra(HomeworkFragment.EXTRA_HOMEWORK_ID, c.getId());
startActivity(i);
```

This starts a whole new `Activity` with it's own lifecycle. Where as this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null); 

transaction.commit();
```

replaces a `Fragment` in `R.id.fragment_container` with `newFragment`.

---

> However, which one should be used and why?

Depends on your needs.

> Additionally, I need to transmit data from the child Fragment
>   (HomeworkFragment) back to the Fragment that launched it in the first
>   place. Which setup allows data (like an id number) to be transmitted
>   easily?

Assuming you have two `Fragment`s, you can use interfaces to transmit the data back to the activity first and then to the second fragment.

Answer (score 1):

One starts an activity.

The other instantiates and attaches a fragment to `fragment_container` which is a part of the calling activity's layout.